# Сетевое программирование под Linux

Tags: c, html, c++, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом с помощью С/C++ можно взаимодействовать с HTML страницей? И можно ли вообще?

С сетями до этого никогда не работал. Углубляться мне сильно не надо, достаточно цифры в `form` вбивать. Заодно буду рад ссылкам на полезные материалы на тему сетевого программирования под Linux вообще.

Comment: [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/)

Comment: Вы хотите эмулировать работу пользователя, заполняющего форму и отправляющего ее на сервер или микро-сервер, получающий запрос от браузера (или другой проги) и отвечающий на него.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> И можно ли вообще?

Можно.

> достаточно цифири в form вбивать.

Задача ясна. Т.е. по сути нужно проэмулировать работу пользователя. Ну, что ж. Я б рекомендовал обратить свое внимание на библиотеку Qt и, в частности, ее компонент [QtWebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit)

Answer (score 5):

Вот есть еще такая библиотечка очень распространенная:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

И пример, как с помощью этой библиотеки работать с формами:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html

Есть в репозиториях всех дистрибутивов Linux (ну может только в каких уж совсем экзотических ее и нет).

Также есть С++ обертка: http://curlpp.org/

Comment: Только язык для этого наверное желательно взять уровнем повыше - чтобы меньше клавиш нажимать.

Comment: Я посмотрел и нашел, что curl эмулирует клиента (например браузер), т.е. он делает connect и т.д.

Из вопроса я не понял, требуется это или наоборот, работа в качестве сервера, т.е. получить запрос, послать форму, получить заполненную форму и т.д.

Возможно я невнимательно смотрел сайт, **подскажите есть ли в curl функции для работы в качестве http сервера** (разбор html видимо есть (пока не смотрел)).

Собственно данный вопрос меня по своей работе интересует (писать или искать библиотеку или выдрать куски из сервера). А тут, как говорится, на ловца и зверь...

Answer (score 0):

Для сетевого программирования в Linux можно использовать Qt. Так же почти в каждой книге по программированию в Linux, написано про сетевое программирование (в основном на си).

Answer (score 0):

Цифири в form вбивать на лине не принято. Если нужно писать серверную часть, то лучше пользоваться непосредственно сокетами. Либо в чистом виде под С, либо в виде разных оберток под Java, PHP, Python и т.д. На самом деле, не так сложно системное программирование, как его малюют. И сокеты в виде системных вызовов тоже не так сложны. Можно основы вполне за пару дней освоить. Другое дело, что придется протокол http ручками прописывать.

Comment: @mikillskegg, о Си библиотеках http-html для серверной части не знаете ?